# Recent Anime where male main character is being chased by an organization that holds underground fights between monsters

Tags: story-identification, anime

I know the organization was criminal in nature. I remember there was betting on the fights. I can't remember if the monsters were summoned there or if the underground place was a lab where they engineered them. I think some of the monsters were human-sized and wore armor if that helps.

I do believe the anime was released fairly recently; within the last 3ish years? The main character had some sort of powers that made him able to easily evade the criminals. I believe the main character escaped the underground facility where they house the fights between monsters.

Comment: Was the main character also a monster? Did they look monstrous? If he isn't a monster, how did he get involved?

Comment: "house the fights" sounds odd; did you mean to say "house the monsters between fights?"

Comment: On the surface, this sounds a lot like the "Sonny's Edge" segment of Love, Death & Robots, an anthology series.  The protagonist, Sonny, is involved in a fighting ring (as in group of criminals, not the actual arena the fights take place in) which pits monstrous creatures, controlled by their handlers, against each other in combat.  It's animated, but not in what I'd associate with an anime style.

Comment: @DavidW "house the fights" does sound slightly odd, but I think they did mean for "house" to modify "the fights between monsters" in the sense of the second definition here (https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/house_2): "to be the place where something is kept, or where an activity is carried out"